# Creating vectors of equal length from R dataset and plotting them

Tags: r

R has some built in datasets, namely I'm using "lynx" and "LakeHuron" which are of different lengths. "lynx" contains data on annual lynx trappings from 1821-1934, and "LakeHuron" contains annual water level from 1872-1975.

I need to plot LakeHuron data on the y-axis, and lynx data on the x-axis, but only for the years 1875-1934 inclusive. I created two vectors:

```
lynx.years = c(lynx)
huron.years = c(LakeHuron)
```

I am stuck at the point of trying to only make a plot for the specified year range. Can someone help me figure out how to plot the data from the two vectors for only the years 1875-1934?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**1)** The question did not specify what sort of plot was desired so assume it is a two panel plot with one series in each panel with years on the X axis such that only the range of years mentioned is shown.  That range of years is the intersection of the years of the two series so:

```
plot(na.omit(cbind(LakeHuron, lynx)))
```

Drop the `na.omit` if you want to plot the entirety of the two series.

**2)** If what is wanted is to rescale the two series so that their shapes can be shown on a single panel despite vastly different ranges:

```
ts.plot(scale(na.omit(cbind(LakeHuron, lynx))), col = 1:2)
```

Again, we could drop the `na.omit` if the entire series were desired.

**3)** If what is wanted is to plot one vs. the other then:

```
plot(unclass(cbind(LakeHuron, lynx)))
```

Comment: Sorry, let me be more specific. It needs to be a point plot. And here is what a sample of the data from LakeHuron looks like: Time Series:
Start = 1875 
End = 1972 
Frequency = 1 
 [1] 580.38 581.86 580.97 580.80 579.79 580.39 580.42 580.82 581.40 581.32
[11] 581.44 581.68 581.17 580.53 580.01 579.91 579.14 579.16 579.55 579.67
[21] 578.44 578.24 579.10 579.09 579.35 578.82 579.32 579.01 579.00 579.80
[31] 579.83 579.72 579.89 580.01 579.37 578.69 578.19 578.67 579.55 578.92
[41] 578.09 579.37 580.13 580.14 579.51 579.24 578.66 578.86 578.05 577.79
[51] 576.75 576.75 577.82 578.64 580.58 579.4

Comment: The closest I've been able to get is: plot(na.omit(cbind(huron.years, lynx.years))). This is almost what I need, but includes ALL data, and I just need to plot data for the year range 1875-1934. So there should be an x-coord for every y-coord. How do I do this?

Comment: I was finally able to achieve what I needed with assistance from your examples, by typing: plot.default(unclass(cbind(LakeHuron, lynx)))